# New to AJAX: Button Click PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

A friend and I were trying to figure out how to create a function that would pull a row(s) from a database based on a value set in a drop down menu. After lots of searching, we got this far, but nothing is happening on click. If I load the php only, I just get the error message with the "old method". Any help would be appreciated. The results will only need to be styled, if that matters in an answer.

(Original AJAX code added) in middle.

THANK YOU!

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type ="text/javascript">

    //      <!-- Change fields to be sourced by field list in future -->
            let FIELD_LIST = [
                            "Any Field",
                            "Animation",
                            "Audio",
                            "Culinary",
                            "Fashion",
                            "Gaming",
                            "Industrial Design",
                            "Interior Design",
                            "Photo",
                            "Video",
                            "Web Design"
                        ];

            let INTEREST_MAP = {
                "Any Field": ["Any Interest"],
                "Animation": ["Modeling", "Motion", "Lighting", "Backgrounds", "Learning Animation"],
                "Audio": ["ADR", "Audio Post", "Composer", "Electrician", "Foley", "Mixer", "On-Set", "Sound Design", "Studio", "Learning Audio"],
                "Culinary": ["Baker", "Catering", "Cuisine (specify)", "Management", "Learning Culinary"],
                "Fashion": ["Costume", "Design", "Marketing", "Tailor", "Wardrobe", "Learning Fashion"],
                "Gaming": ["3D Artist", "Animator", "Art Director", "Concept Artist", "Environment Artist", "Game Tester", "Modeler", "Motion Capture", "Project Manager", "Programmer", "UI Artist", "Learning Gaming"],
                "Industrial Design": ["Product", "Learning Industrial Design"],
                "Interior Design": ["Commercial", "Drafting", "Environment", "Hospitality", "Institution", "Residential", "Learning Interior"],
                "Photo": ["Commercial", "Event", "Fashion", "Narrative", "Nature", "Real Estate", "Sports", "Wedding", "Learning Photo"],
                "Video": ["Cinematographer", "Director", "Editor", "Producer", "Production Assistant", "Scriptwriter", "Learning Video"],
                "Web Design": ["Developing", "Interface", "Typography", "User Experience", "Learning Web Design"]
            };      

            function populate2(fieldId, interestId) {
                let field = document.getElementById(fieldId).value;
                let interestList = document.getElementById(interestId);
                interestList.innerHTML = "";
                for(let interest in INTEREST_MAP[field]){
                    let newOption = document.createElement("option");
                    newOption.value = INTEREST_MAP[field][interest];
                    newOption.innerHTML = INTEREST_MAP[field][interest];
                    interestList.options.add(newOption);
                }
            }
    //      $(document).ready(function(){
    //     $("#collaborate").click(function(){
    //         $.get("Profiles.php", function(data){
    //             alert("Data: " + data);
    //         });
    //     });
    // });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#collaborate').click(function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.get('userprofiles.php', {ajax: true},function(data, status){
                        alert(data);
                    });
                });
            });

    </script>
<div id="container">

  <div class="column">
      <select class="field" name="field"  id="field" onchange="populate2('field','interestId')" >
            <option value="Any Field">Any Field</option>
            <option value="Animation">Animation</option>
            <option value="Audio">Audio</option>
            <option value="Culinary">Culinary</option>
            <option value="Fashion">Fashion</option>
            <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
            <option value="Industrial Design">Industrial Design</option>
            <option value="Interior Design">Interior Design</option>
            <option value="Photo">Photo</option>
            <option value="Video">Video</option>
            <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
      </select>
      <h1 class="info1">1</h1>
      <h3 class="info1">Select an artist's field of choice you need</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <select class= "interestId" name="interestId" id="interestId">
        <option value="Any Interest">Any Interest</option>
      </select>
          <h1 class="info2">2</h1>
              <h3 class="info2">Select a specific interest you're looking for</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <button class="button" id="collaborate" name="collaborate">
        Collaborate!
    </button>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

ORIGINAL AJAX CODE (from my friend's understanding)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#collaborate').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "userprofiles.php",
                    data: { 'interest' : "asd" } // this line does nothing at the moment. But ideally it is used to pass data directly as variables to your php document.
                }).done(function( result ) {
                    // alert( "Data Saved: " + result );
                    $('#data').text(data);
                });
            });
        });
```

PHP

```
 $Interest = $_GET['interestId'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from User WHERE Interest1='$Interest' OR Interest2='$Interest' OR Interest3 ='$Interest'";

   $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    //  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    //  echo "<pre>";
    //  print_r($row);
    //  echo "</pre>";

    // attempt select query execution

// OLD METHOD BELOW
    if ($result) {
        print_r($result);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
```

Comment: "Nothing is happening on click". You'll first need to track down where exactly this is failing - is the click handler firing? Is the ajax failing? Is the query failing?  Place an alert in your click handler to see if it's being fired at all.  Open up your browser console and look for errors as well.

Comment: That's what we're confused about. There are no errors. I'm not knowledgable with the debugger, but my friend is. He stepped through  our original code, which I will add, and didn't find any issues. I decided to change it and see if I could get it to work.

Comment: Please give the details along with the code. Not just the whole page code . Explain briefly

Comment: @AnikethSaha Can you explain what more detail you need? I'm a novice when it comes to programming (friend is much better) but this is something we both aren't having luck with.

Comment: So basically what you want is: "I want to pull a record from DB when the button labelled Collaborate is clicked"?

Comment: Basically, yes. There is value that the button would look for and pull records based on that value.

Comment: What you want is whenever you are clicking thr drop down menu it will send the data to db and retrieve based on this value ri8? Ok so show the `populate2` method . Now whenever the onChange fires the event send the value to php and fetch as you did its correct only . Now your php has an error first of all  the result should be looped and just dont send the data by echoing . Save it to a another variable and in the loop concatenate this variable and at last echo this variable . And dont use `print_r` use echo to send the final concatenate value

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. It sounds like I'm doing some thing correct but some not? Do you have an example you can show to help me grasp what you're saying? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just decided to go with wrapping my drop downs into a form and styling it back to it's original shape. PHP works like a charm this way.

Comment: While this is what you've done, it is by no means an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your php instead of using print_r()

```
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Then in your jQuery

```
alert(JSON.parse(data));
```

how this helps

Comment: All it gave was an error in the HTML related to the alert.